# Field level permissions in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, nodes, entities

What is the best way to create a piece of content with multiple fields... allowing users to edit the content as a whole yet blocking the ability to edit.

The setup I have is a piece of content that has 3 fields: Body, PDF, SWF... and a "Selector" (List Text) that's tied via dependancy. So the user chooses BODY, PDF or SWF and that's what available to edit and shown on the page when live.

What I want to do is add a PHP field... that's either:

- greyed out (unable to edit) if your not admin...
- doesn't show up in the Drop Down list... Can't select it if you can't see it
- Shows up on the drop down, but the field doesn't show up in the editor without permissions.

I hope I'm making sense... I can provide an example if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Drupal 7, check out http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions.

> The Field Permissions module is a drop-in replacement for the Content
>   Permissions module shipped with CCK.

So for Drupal 6, use the Content Permissions module shipped with CCK

Comment: Didn't see that module. I'll give it a whirl, sounds perfect for what I want.